# Handling json parse play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

If i'm not mistaken, this `BodyParsers.parse.json` would parse `request.body` to json

```
def getUser(id: Int) = Action (BodyParsers.parse.json) { implicit request =>
    var parsedJson = request.body.validate[MyCustomUserModel]
    parsedJson.fold(
    errors => {
          println("Something wrong...")
    },
    obj => {
         println("This would be my name : " + obj.name)
         println("This would be my age : " + obj.age)
    }
    Ok(Json.obj("status"->"Ok"))
}
```

however, if there were no body sent at all, or the json does not match all the required model, it will throw exceptions. I wonder if it is possible to handle these errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse your request body with `parse.json`, you should guarantee that the content-type of your request is 'application/json', which can be checked by the following code:

```
val contentType = request.contentType
play.api.Logger.info("contentType: " + contentType)// just check the log info
```

Another thing you will do when you use `request.body.validate[MyCustomUserModel]` is to define the `Json Reads` for your case class. For example, your `MyCustomerUserModel` is defined like this following:

```
case class MyCustomUserModel(name: String, age: Int)
```

the `Reads[myCustomUserModel]` will be defined like this:

```
implicit val myCustomUserModelReads: Reads[MyCustomUserModel] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "age").read[Int]
)(MyCustomUserModel.apply _)
```

Good luck with you